# CKEditor not shown when i download js file from server

Tags: ckeditor

Below script reference getting cke js from server

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.0/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

When I download from this server and add manually my project CKEditor not shown.
what is the difference two situation?

Answer (score 2):

You've downloaded only one file "ckeditor.js" but it tries to load many other files  (images, css, language files, dialogs, ...) so it can't work that way.

You should download instead the full package that you can deploy to your server: http://ckeditor.com/download